# Loading texture - using OpenGl, LWJGL and SlickUtil

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I get this error when I try to load a texture. Any ideas on why this has occured? or if the method has changed since I last used the libraries?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGetInteger(ILjava/nio/IntBuffer;)V
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.renderer.ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.glGetInteger(ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.java:194)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:317)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:254)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:200)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:64)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:24)
at engine.Loader.loadTexture(Loader.java:39)
at game.Game.main(Game.java:51)
```

My code to load a texture is this.

```
public int loadTexture(String fileName){
    Texture texture = null;
    try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream("res/" + fileName + ".png"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int textureID = texture.getTextureID();
    textures.add(textureID);
    return textureID;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are using incompatible versions of the lwjgl/slick2d libraries...

Comment: Which LWJGL version are you using?

Comment: LWJGL - build #3.0.0b build 64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slick-Util is not compatible with LWJGL 3 and it is unsure whether it will be continued. There seems to be a [version that works with it](http://slick.ninjacave.com/slick-util3.zip), but I haven't tried it.

The LWJGL developers recommend using the included STB library for loading textures because it is still being developed, lightweight and quite good at loading simple files. You can have a look at the [tests](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/tree/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/stb) and the [getting started guide](https://github.com/SilverTiger/lwjgl3-tutorial/wiki/Textures) for examples of how to use it.